# Show that $\Pr(X_n = 0 \text{ infinitely often}) = 0$ using variance, expectation, and $X_n ≥ 0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Hi I'm really struggling with where to go on the following question.

QUESTION:

Let $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random variables defined on a probability space $(\Omega, F, \Pr)$ such that $X_n ≥ 0,$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$
Suppose that $\operatorname{Var}(X_n) ≤ n^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $E(X_n) = n.$
Show that $\Pr(X_n = 0 \text{ infinitely often}) = 0.$

I am aware of the Borel-Cantelli lemma (below)
Let $(E_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N} }$ be a collection of events on some probability space $(Ω, F, Pr)$. The following holds:

1. If $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \Pr(E_n) <\infty$ then $\Pr(E_n \text{ occurs
       infinitely often}) = 0$
2. If $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \Pr(E_n) =\infty$ then $\Pr(E_n \text{ occurs
       infinitely often}) = 1$

I am lost at how to use the information given to apply this lemma (assuming that I should use this lemma?)

Final Edit:

Thank you for the help! This is what I have put as my final answer

$\Pr(X_n = 0 \text{ infinitely often}) = \Pr({\{ \omega | X_n(\omega)=0 \; \forall  n \in \mathbb{N}}\}).$

Use Chebyschev's inequality, choosing $t$ such that $ {\{\omega | X_n(\omega)=0 }\}\subseteq {\{\omega | \lvert X_n(\omega) -n \rvert  \geqslant t}\}$ and so the resulting bound is summable
Let $t=\frac{n}{2}$ then
$\Pr(X_n = 0 )\leq \Pr(\lvert X_n -n \rvert \geqslant \frac{n}{2})\leq 4n^{-\frac{3}{2}}.$
Now $ \sum^\infty _{n=1} 4n^{-\frac{3}{2}} = 4 \sum^\infty _{n=1} \frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}} $ is a p series of the form $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^p}$, which converges if $p>1$ and diverges otherwise. Here, $p=\frac{3}{2}>1$ which implies convergence.
Therefore
$\ \sum^\infty _{n=1} 4n^{-\frac{3}{2}} < \infty $.
Thus
$\ \sum^\infty_{n=1} \Pr(X_n = 0 )\leq \sum^\infty_{n=1} \Pr(\lvert X_n -n \rvert \geqslant \frac{n}{2})\leq \sum^\infty_{n=1} 4n^{-\frac{3}{2}}<\infty$.
So $\ \sum^\infty_{n=1} \Pr(X_n = 0 )<\infty$.

From the first Borel-Cantelli Lemma, if $\ \sum^\infty_{n=1}\Pr(E_n) <\infty \text{ then } \Pr(\{E_n \text{ occurs infinitely often }\})=0 $.

Therefore $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \Pr(X_n = 0 )<\infty \Rightarrow \Pr(\{X_n=0 \text{ occurs infinitely often }\})=0$ as required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\displaystyle p[X_n = 0] \le p\left[|X_n-n| \ge {n \over 2}\right] \le 4 {\sqrt{n} \over n^2}$ from Chebyshev.

Comment: Thanks Michael.

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask what made you pick n/2 as the t value?

Comment: @H99: I just needed to make sure that $\{ \omega | X_n(\omega)=0 \}$ was contained in the corresponding 'Chebyshev' set and the resulting bound be summable. ${n \over 2}$ was the first I tried and it worked.